# EXPO Image Error Canvas: trying to use a recycled bitmap android.graphics.Bitmap@

Tags: android, reactjs, react-native, expo

I am building a long list FlatList slider using expo, and the slider's Items are full screen images and I am using Expo Image library, everything is working fine on IOS devices, but on Android **Sometimes** the app crashes when I navigate to the screen when the slider is, and go to the specific index where I left the slider using the FlatList's property `initialScrollIndex`,
The crash happens when the FlatList go to this specific index,

```js
return (<View style={styles.container}>
      <FlatList
        data={dataArray}
        renderItem={_renderItem}
        viewabilityConfigCallbackPairs={viewabilityConfigCallbackPairs.current}
        showsHorizontalScrollIndicator={false}
        bounces={false}
        decelerationRate="normal"
        keyExtractor={_keyExtractor}
        windowSize={3}
        initialNumToRender={1}
        initialScrollIndex={route?.params?.currentPageNumber}
        getItemLayout={_getItemLayout}
        horizontal
        inverted
        pagingEnabled
        snapToStart
      />
    </View>);


const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
  },
});
```

I'm getting this crash(Android Only):

````
     ERROR:  Your app just crashed. See the error below.**
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Canvas: trying to use a recycled bitmap 
    android.graphics.Bitmap@2703e43
    android.graphics.BaseCanvas.throwIfCannotDraw(BaseCanvas.java:98)
    android.graphics.RecordingCanvas.throwIfCannotDraw(RecordingCanvas.java:263)
    android.graphics.BaseRecordingCanvas.drawBitmap(BaseRecordingCanvas.java:94)
    android.graphics.drawable.BitmapDrawable.draw(BitmapDrawable.java:549)
    android.widget.ImageView.onDraw(ImageView.java:1446)
    expo.modules.image.ExpoImageView.onDraw(ExpoImageView.kt:186)
    android.view.View.draw(View.java:23481)
    expo.modules.image.ExpoImageView.draw(ExpoImageView.kt:182)
    android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:22299)
    android.view.View.draw(View.java:23191)
    android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:4602)
    android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:4360)
    android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:22288)
    android.view.View.draw(View.java:23191)
  android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:4602)
  android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:4360)
  android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:22288)
  android.view.View.draw(View.java:23191)
  android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:4602)
  com.facebook.react.views.view.ReactViewGroup.drawChild(ReactViewGroup.java:836)
  android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:4360)
  com.facebook.react.views.view.ReactViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ReactViewGroup.java:809)
  android.view.View.draw(View.java:23490)
  android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:22299)
  android.view.View.draw(View.java:23191)
  android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:4602)
  com.facebook.react.views.view.ReactViewGroup.drawChild(ReactViewGroup.java:836)
  android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:4360)
  com.facebook.react.views.view.ReactViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ReactViewGroup.java:809)
  android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:22288)
  android.view.View.draw(View.java:23191)
  android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:4602)
  com.facebook.react.views.view.ReactViewGroup.drawChild(ReactViewGroup.java:836)
  android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:4360)
  com.facebook.react.views.view.ReactViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ReactViewGroup.java:809)
  android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:22288)
  android.view.View.draw(View.java:23191)
  android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:4602)
  android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:4360)
  android.view.View.draw(View.java:23490)
  android.widget.HorizontalScrollView.draw(HorizontalScrollView.java:1777)
  com.facebook.react.views.scroll.ReactHorizontalScrollView.draw(ReactHorizontalScrollView.java:746)
  android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:22299)
  android.view.View.draw(View.java:23191)
  android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:4602)
  com.facebook.react.views.view.ReactViewGroup.drawChild(ReactViewGroup.java:836)
  android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:4360)
  com.facebook.react.views.view.ReactViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ReactViewGroup.java:809)
  android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:22288)
  android.view.ViewGroup.recreateChildDisplayList(ViewGroup.java:4586)
  android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchGetDisplayList(ViewGroup.java:4559)
  android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:22239)
  android.view.ViewGroup.recreateChildDisplayList(ViewGroup.java:4586)
  android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchGetDisplayList(ViewGroup.java:4559)
  android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:22239)
  android.view.ViewGroup.recreateChildDisplayList(ViewGroup.java:4586)
  android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchGetDisplayList(ViewGroup.java:4559)
  android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:22239)
  android.view.ViewGroup.recreateChildDisplayList(ViewGroup.java:4586)
  android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchGetDisplayList(ViewGroup.java:4559)
  android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:22239)
  android.view.ViewGroup.recreateChildDisplayList(ViewGroup.java:4586)
  android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchGetDisplayList(ViewGroup.java:4559)
  android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:22239)
  android.view.ViewGroup.recreateChildDisplayList(ViewGroup.java:4586)
  android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchGetDisplayList(ViewGroup.java:4559)
  android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:22239)
  android.view.ViewGroup.recreateChildDisplayList(ViewGroup.java:4586)
  android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchGetDisplayList(ViewGroup.java:4559)
  android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:22239)
  android.view.ViewGroup.recreateChildDisplayList(ViewGroup.java:4586)
  android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchGetDisplayList(ViewGroup.java:4559)
  android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:22239)
  android.view.ViewGroup.recreateChildDisplayList(ViewGroup.java:4586)
  android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchGetDisplayList(ViewGroup.java:4559)
  android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:22239)
  android.view.ViewGroup.recreateChildDisplayList(ViewGroup.java:4586)
  android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchGetDisplayList(ViewGroup.java:4559)
  android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:22239)
  android.view.ViewGroup.recreateChildDisplayList(ViewGroup.java:4586)
  android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchGetDisplayList(ViewGroup.java:4559)
  android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:22239)
  android.view.ViewGroup.recreateChildDisplayList(ViewGroup.java:4586)
  android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchGetDisplayList(ViewGroup.java:4559)
  android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:22239)
  android.view.ViewGroup.recreateChildDisplayList(ViewGroup.java:4586)
  android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchGetDisplayList(ViewGroup.java:4559)
  android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:22239)
  android.view.ViewGroup.recreateChildDisplayList(ViewGroup.java:4586)
  android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchGetDisplayList(ViewGroup.java:4559)
  android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:22239)
  android.view.ViewGroup.recreateChildDisplayList(ViewGroup.java:4586)
  android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchGetDisplayList(ViewGroup.java:4559)
  android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:22239)
  android.view.ViewGroup.recreateChildDisplayList(ViewGroup.java:4586)
  android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchGetDisplayList(ViewGroup.java:4559)
  android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:22239)
  android.view.ViewGroup.recreateChildDisplayList(ViewGroup.java:4586)
  android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchGetDisplayList(ViewGroup.java:4559)
  android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:22239)
  android.view.ThreadedRenderer.updateViewTreeDisplayList(ThreadedRenderer.java:682)
  android.view.ThreadedRenderer.updateRootDisplayList(ThreadedRenderer.java:690)
  android.view.ThreadedRenderer.draw(ThreadedRenderer.java:795)
  android.view.ViewRootImpl.draw(ViewRootImpl.java:4992)
  android.view.ViewRootImpl.performDraw(ViewRootImpl.java:4681)
  android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:3868)
  android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:2577)
  android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:9638)
  android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:1386)
  android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:1394)
  android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:1013)
  android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:911)
  android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:1366)
  android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:942)
      android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
     android.os.Looper.loopOnce(Looper.java:211)
     android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:300)
     android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:8152)
     java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
     com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:580)
     com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1028)```

Any help is appreciated.
````